# Не сохранять пустые странички при разделении А4 на четвертинки А6

Tags: python, pdf

Как разделять я научился и при помощи PyPDF2 и при помощи PyMuPDF(fitz). Но при разделении часто бывает что текст есть только в одной четвертинке, но он записывает в новый файл все 4 четвертинки и с текстом и пустые, одна с текстом остальные пустые, а мне нужно что-бы пустые не сохранялись, хотел как то сделать проверку, но не получилось, не хватает знаний. Пытался прочитать по новой записанный файл и удалить пустые странички, но там есть текст на каждой страничке даже на пустых, я открываю файл в acrobat reader но там странички пустые, не пойму как так.

Вот мой код на всякий случай как и что делаю: https://paste.aiogram.dev/opiquhehus.py

Первый раз сюда пишу и не знаю как файлы прикрепить.
pdf файлы для примера в телеграм канале: https://t.me/+Tq7WpP1ImcjQXSZF.

```
import copy
import logging
import random
from pathlib import Path

import PyPDF2
import fitz
from PyPDF2.filters import decodeStreamData, ASCII85Decode
from PyPDF2.generic import EncodedStreamObject, DecodedStreamObject


def from_a4_to_a6_not_sync(input_file, output_file):
    input_file = str(input_file.absolute())

    pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(input_file)

    # print(f'{pdf_reader.getNumPages()=}')
    # print(f'{pdf_reader.documentInfo=}')

    first_page = pdf_reader.getPage(0)

    left_up_side = copy.deepcopy(first_page)
    right_up_side = copy.deepcopy(first_page)
    left_down_side = copy.deepcopy(first_page)
    right_down_side = copy.deepcopy(first_page)

    # print(f'{left_up_side.extractText()=}')
    # print(f'{right_up_side.extractText()=}')
    # print(f'\nДО ОБРЕЗКИ:\n{type(left_up_side)=}\n{left_up_side=}\n')
    # print(f'\nДО ОБРЕЗКИ:\n{type(right_up_side)=}\n{right_up_side=}\n')

    # second_page = pdf_reader.getPage(0)
    # print(f'{type(second_page)=}\n{second_page.extractText()=}')
    # third_page = pdf_reader.getPage(0)
    # fourth_page = pdf_reader.getPage(0)

    first_coord = first_page.mediaBox.upperRight[0]
    second_coord = first_page.mediaBox.upperRight[1]
    # print(f'{first_coord=}')
    # print(f'{second_coord=}')

    # cords_upperLeft = first_page.mediaBox.upperLeft
    # cords_lowerLeft = first_page.mediaBox.lowerLeft
    # cords_upperRight = first_page.mediaBox.upperRight
    # cords_lowerRight = first_page.mediaBox.lowerRight
    # print(f'{cords_upperLeft=}')
    # print(f'{cords_lowerLeft=}')
    # print(f'{cords_upperRight=}')
    # print(f'{cords_lowerRight=}')

    # first_page.mediaBox.lowerRight = (first_coord / 2, second_coord / 2)  # ВЕРХНЯЯ ЛЕВАЯ ЧЕТВЕРТИНКА
    # second_page.mediaBox.lowerLeft = (first_coord / 2, second_coord / 2)  #   ВЕРХНЯЯ ПРАВАЯ ЧЕТВЕРТИНКА
    # third_page.mediaBox.upperRight = (first_coord / 2, second_coord / 2)  #   НИЖНЯЯ ЛЕВАЯ ЧЕТВЕРТИНКА
    # fourth_page.mediaBox.upperLeft = (first_coord / 2, second_coord / 2)  # НИЖНЯЯ ПРАВАЯ ЧЕТВЕРТИНКА

    left_up_side.mediaBox.lowerRight = (first_coord / 2, second_coord / 2)  # ВЕРХНЯЯ ЛЕВАЯ ЧЕТВЕРТИНКА
    right_up_side.mediaBox.lowerLeft = (first_coord / 2, second_coord / 2)  # ВЕРХНЯЯ ПРАВАЯ ЧЕТВЕРТИНКА
    left_down_side.mediaBox.upperRight = (first_coord / 2, second_coord / 2)  # НИЖНЯЯ ЛЕВАЯ ЧЕТВЕРТИНКА
    right_down_side.mediaBox.upperLeft = (first_coord / 2, second_coord / 2)  # НИЖНЯЯ ПРАВАЯ ЧЕТВЕРТИНКА

    # print(f'{first_page=}\n\n')
    # one_page = left_up_side.getContents()
    # second_page = right_up_side.getContents()
    # decode_one = DecodedStreamObject()
    # print(f'{decode_one.getData()}')
    # print(f'{decodeStreamData(second_page)}')

    # print(f'ПОСЛЕ ОБРЕЗКИ:\n{type(left_up_side)=}\n{left_up_side=}\n')
    # print(f'{left_up_side.extractText().encode("utf8")=} {type(left_up_side.extractText())=}')
    # print(f'{right_up_side.extractText().encode("utf8")=} {type(right_up_side.extractText())=}')
    # print(f'{left_up_side.getContents()=} {type(left_up_side.getContents())=}')
    # print(f'{right_up_side.getContents()=} {type(right_up_side.getContents())=}')
    # print(f'\nПОСЛЕ ОБРЕЗКИ:\n{type(left_up_side)=}\n{left_up_side=}\n')
    # print(f'\nПОСЛЕ ОБРЕЗКИ:\n{type(right_up_side)=}\n{right_up_side=}\n')

    pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
    # pdf_writer.addPage(first_page)
    pdf_writer.addPage(left_up_side)
    pdf_writer.addPage(right_up_side)

    with open(output_file, 'wb') as file:
        pdf_writer.write(file)
        file.close()


def fitz_four_piaces(input_file, output_file):
    input_file = str(input_file.absolute())

    src = fitz.open(input_file)
    doc = fitz.open()  # empty output PDF
    page = 0

    for spage in src:  # for each page in input
        r = spage.rect  # input page rectangle
        d = fitz.Rect(spage.cropbox_position,  # CropBox displacement if not
                      spage.cropbox_position)  # starting at (0, 0)

        # --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # example: cut input page into 2 x 2 parts
        # --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        r1 = r / 2  # top left rect
        r2 = r1 + (r1.width, 0, r1.width, 0)  # top right rect
        r3 = r1 + (0, r1.height, 0, r1.height)  # bottom left rect
        r4 = fitz.Rect(r1.br, r.br)  # bottom right rect
        rect_list = [r1, r2, r3, r4]  # put them in a list

        for rx in rect_list:  # run thru rect list
            count = 0 # почему-то не считает
            rx += d  # add the CropBox displacement
            # print(f'{rx=}')
            page = doc.new_page(-1,  # new output page with rx dimensions
                                width=rx.width,
                                height=rx.height)
            page.show_pdf_page(
                page.rect,  # fill all new page with the image
                src,  # input document
                spage.number,  # input page number
                clip=rx,  # which part to use of input page
            )
            # print(f'{spage.number=}')
            # text_in_page = page.get_text("text")#.encode("utf8")
            # print(f'{text_in_page=}')
            # print(f'{count=} {doc.get_page_text(doc.page_count - 1)=}')
            # print(f'in cicle {doc.page_count - 1=}')
            count += 1

    # that's it, save output file
    # print(f'{doc.metadata=}')
    # print(f'{doc.page_count=}')
    doc.save(output_file,  #
             garbage=3,  # eliminate duplicate objects
             deflate=True,  # compress stuff where possible
             )
    # input_file2 = str(output_file.absolute())
    # src2 = fitz.open(input_file2)
    # print(f'{src2.page_count=}')
    # for page in src2:
    #     print(f'{page.get_text("words")=}')


def fitz_four_piaces_read(input_file):
    input_file = str(input_file.absolute())
    src = fitz.open(input_file)
    print(f'{src.page_count=}')
    for page in src:
        print(f'{page.get_text("text")=}')


destination = Path().joinpath("MAKETS")
destination.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
destination_input = destination.joinpath(
    f'up_lef.pdf')  # up_lef_up_rig_low_lef_low_rig

destination_output = destination.joinpath(
    f'output_a6_{random.randint(1, 100)}_{random.randint(1, 200)}.pdf')  # f'output_a6_{random.randint(1, 100)}_{random.randint(1, 200)}.pdf'

# from_a4_to_a6_not_sync(destination_input, destination_output)

fitz_four_piaces(destination_input, destination_output)
fitz_four_piaces_read(destination_output)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено! Нужно после разделения страницы на 4 части, переобразовывать получившиеся страницы в картинки и потом сравнивать размер. Поделюсь кодом, может быть кому-то будет полезно)

```
import os

import fitz


def get_size(filename):
    st = os.stat(filename)
    return st.st_size


async def from_a4_to_a6(input_file, output_file):
    input_file = str(input_file.absolute())

    src = fitz.open(input_file)
    doc = fitz.open()  # empty output PDF

    for spage in src:  # for each page in input
        r = spage.rect  # input page rectangle
        d = fitz.Rect(spage.cropbox_position,  # CropBox displacement if not
                      spage.cropbox_position)  # starting at (0, 0)
        # --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # example: cut input page into 2 x 2 parts
        # --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        r1 = r / 2  # top left rect
        r2 = r1 + (r1.width, 0, r1.width, 0)  # top right rect
        r3 = r1 + (0, r1.height, 0, r1.height)  # bottom left rect
        r4 = fitz.Rect(r1.br, r.br)  # bottom right rect
        rect_list = [r1, r2, r3, r4]  # put them in a list

        for rx in rect_list:  # run thru rect list
            rx += d  # add the CropBox displacement
            page = doc.new_page(-1,  # new output page with rx dimensions
                                width=rx.width,
                                height=rx.height)
            page.show_pdf_page(
                page.rect,  # fill all new page with the imageb
                src,  # input document
                spage.number,  # input page number
                clip=rx,  # which part to use of input page
            )
            # Тут мы переобразуем пдф в картинку и проверим размер
            pix = page.get_pixmap()  # render page to an image
            name_png = f"page-{page.number}.png"  # _{random.randint(1,100)}
            pix.save(name_png)  # store image as a PNG
            imgsize = get_size(name_png)
            os.remove(name_png)
            if imgsize < 1300:  #  Размер пустой страницы А6 примерно 1209 у Вас может быть другой, проверьте сначала.
                doc.delete_page(pno=-1)
                break

    doc.save(output_file,
             garbage=4,  # eliminate duplicate objects
             clean=True,
             deflate=True,  # compress stuff where possible
             )
```